# Long term visa from Italy

Tags: schengen, applications, long-stay-visas

My wife and I are working full time in the UK. I got a 3 months Schengen Multi Entry visa from Germany. It ends on June 2024. This was my first Schengen visa.

My father-in-law lives in Italy and we would like to visit him (like once every 2 months).

Can we apply for a long term visa rather than applying every 3 months (or 6)?

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: @DJClayworth does the answer actually vary among visa-required (Annex I) countries?

Comment: @mlc I don't think so. Although the spouse's citizenship might be relevant if it is an EU country.

Answer (score 4):

> Can we apply for a long term visa rather than applying every 3 months (or 6)?

Yes, you can do so. Whether or not it would be granted depends on the mood of your local consular employee. I’m an EU citizen and my own (non EU citizen) grandma only managed to get 1 year tourist visas at a time despite having traveled dozens of times to the Schengen area without a single overstay. Some people get lucky and get two or five year visas for subsequent visits.

Answer (score -3):

> Can we apply for a long term visa rather than applying every 3 months (or 6)?

No, since your main purpose is to **visit** (not to reside) in Italy. For a visit every 2 months, the visit *duration* of 90 days in any 180-day period is suffient.

With time the *validity* of the **Schengen Visa** (type C, short-term) will become longer (1,2 years, then 5 years).

A **National Visa** (type D, long-term) are generelly issued for the purpose of taking up **residence** or another purpose for periods up to **1 year** (i.e **longer than 90 days**).

Comment: Note for the downvoters: this question has been tagged as: **long-stay-visas**: *European "Long Stay Visas", also known as "National Visas" or "Type D Visas". Used when visiting countries in the Schengen area for longer than the 90 days maximum of a Schengen visa.*

Comment: It is very obvious from the question that OP with 'long term' means a C visa with a longer validity than 3 months.

Comment: @Tor-Einar Jarnbjo Yes and that was adressed in the answer.